# react-router-dom : How to do async calls to decide to render a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, react-router-dom

I have an isAuthenticated method that sends the access_token to the verification endpoint. if the response has an error I send the refresh_token to the refresh endpoint and whenever I get the new access token I save it in localStorage and ...

This method is async and I use it to decide to render a component or not.

```
const AuthenticatedRoute = ({ children, ...rest }) => {
    const auth = useContext(AuthContext);
    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            **render={() => {
                return auth.isAuthenticated() ? (**
                    <>{children}</>
                ) : (
                    <Redirect to="/login" />
                );
            }}
        ></Route>
    );
};
```

I can't give an async method to the render method. I totally confused about how to handle this situation. maybe my strategy is wrong. can I somehow use isAuthenticated to decide to render a component in this strategy?

Answer (score 0):

I think. Run async method in useEffect to change state

```
const AuthenticatedRoute = ({ children, ...rest }) => {
    const auth = useContext(AuthContext);
    const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
    
    useEffect(() => {
       setIsAuthenticated(auth.isAuthenticated())
    },[auth])
    
    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
                render={() => {
                return isAuthenticated ? (
                    <>{children}</>
                ) : (
                    <Redirect to="/login" />
                );
            }}
        ></Route>
    );
};
```